# read ConnectionString from appsettings.json for entity.Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

i try to read a ConnectiongString from appsettings.json for entityFramework and MySQL, but i get the error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
```

this is my appsetings.json:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "server=database;userid=hawai;pwd=mysecret;port=3306;database=identity;sslmode=none;",
      "MigrationConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;userid=hawai;pwd=mysecret;port=3306;database=identity;sslmode=none;"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my Startup:

```
    public class Startup
        {
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

            public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration = builder.Build();

            }

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {


                    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MigrationConnection");
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MigrationConnection")));


                services.AddMvc();
}
```

and this is my DBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextOptions) :
            base(dbContextOptions)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

if i change the "MigrationConnection" with:

```
server=127.0.0.1;userid=xxx;pwd=xxx;port=3306;database=xxx;sslmode=none;
```

what could it be?

Comment: The ConnectionStrings key is not on root `Data > ConnectionString > MigrationConnection` so `GetConnectionString("MigrationConnection")` is not goign to find it. Either update path in code or update settings file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because `Configuration.GetConnectionString("MigrationConnection")` returns `null`. It should be replaced with:

```
var connection = Configuration.GetSection("Data").GetConnectionString("MigrationConnection");
```

Or you can change the structure of appsettings.json to:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "server=database;userid=hawai;pwd=mysecret;port=3306;database=identity;sslmode=none;",
      "MigrationConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;userid=hawai;pwd=mysecret;port=3306;database=identity;sslmode=none;"
    }  
}
```