# EF Core DbContext sql connection string error (Tried Following info in MS Docs)

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, dbcontext

I have a .net Core application and I've been attempting to read from my local instance of SQL Server (2014) with Windows Authentication and continue to run into a repeat error about my connection string. I've been reviewing the MSDN docs as well as connectionstrings.com and thought I had everything configured correctly.

This is my error:

> "System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does
>   not conform to specification starting at index 0.'"

Which I take to mean the very start of my connection string.

**I have read the other posts related to this exact issue but haven't been able to use them to find a solution.**

Here is what I attempt when the error occurs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private ModelContext _context;

  public HomeController()
  {}

  public IActionResult Index()
  {
      var viewModel = new HomeViewModel();

      var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelContext>();
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection");

      using (_context = new ModelContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
      {
        >>>>>> viewModel.List = _context.TableName.ToList(); <<<<<<<<
```

I have the following in my **"appsettings.json"** file:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=MyComputerName; Database=DBName; IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;"
 },
```

In my "ModelContext.cs" file

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
  public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options)
      :base(options)
  { }

  [<Table Properties>]

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection");
  }
```

And **"Startup.cs"** file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
         Configuration = configuration;
    } 

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options =>   
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I've already reviewed [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306119/read-connectionstring-from-appsettings-json-for-entity-framework] (Reading ConnectionString from json file) and tried that but am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After much contemplation and re-review of the MS Documents site for [EF Core DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext), I found that I was attempting to implement ALL 3 methods of DbContext configuration: Constructor Argument, OnConfiguring, and dependency injection.

Decided to go with OnConfiguring to get the app moving.